# Intercepting calls to rm, and directing deleted files to trash instead

Tags: delete, trash

Is there a way to intercept calls to rm, and instead of permamently deleting the files, moving them to trash instead?

Comment: How universal are you asking? Do you mean for every rm call by every user or process? Or just for you while you're using bash? Or..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*There's a [recipe on webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/make-rm-move-files-to-trash-instead-of.html) for this. To prevent link rot, here's the important information (with a few additions).*

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

This will install `trash`, `empty-trash`, `list-trash` and `restore-trash` commands, which you can use as-is or make `rm` an alias of `trash` (see below).

The semantic of the `trash` command is a bit different then the standard `rm` - it doesn't require `-r` flag in order to be able to delete directories. If this bothers you, webupd8.org proposes the following script, which you can put in your PATH and call it `trash-rm`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# command name: trash-rm
shopt -s extglob
recursive=1
declare -a cmd
((i = 0))
for f in "$@"; do
    case "$f" in

        (-*([fiIv])r*([fiIv])|-*([fiIv])R*([fiIv]))
            tmp="${f//[rR]/}"
            if [ -n "$tmp" ]; then
                #echo "\$tmp == $tmp"
                cmd[$i]="$tmp"
                ((i++))
            fi
            recursive=0
        ;;

        (--recursive) recursive=0
        ;;

        (*)
            if [ $recursive != 0   -a  -d "$f" ]; then
                echo "skipping directory: $f"
                continue
            else
                cmd[$i]="$f"
                ((i++))
            fi
        ;;

    esac
done
trash "${cmd[@]}"
```

In Ubuntu 12.04 and later, the last command in the script should be `trash-put "${cmd[@]}"` instead of `trash "${cmd[@]}"` (as the command has changed from `trash` to `trash-put`).

Then make the script executable:

```
chmod +x trash-rm
```

Once you have it in some directory in your `PATH`, add an alias to your ~/.bashrc, which will make bash to invoke your script instead of the actual `rm` command:

```
alias rm="trash-rm"
```

As djeikyb correctly points out, the .bashrc alias trick would only work for the user whose .bashrc is modified, and only in bash terminal session.

And that should be it.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be even better if you reorganised it to emphasise the main concept of using an alias. I think it's most important to understand how to "intercept" rm. What happens in its place can be customised any number of ways.

Comment: Also, it'd be good to mention that this only affects the rm command for the user's bash session.

Comment: @djeikyb: thanks for the suggesions, I updated the answer

Comment: It works great for me without the script (just installed and add `alias="trash"`). Do you know what is the advantage of having the script?

Comment: @desgua: the purpose of the script is to make `trash` to behave more like `rm` in regards to deleting directories. This may be important for some scripts which expect `rm` to work the way it does, for example. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[libtrash](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/software/libtrash/) (package libtrash in Ubuntu) seems to do this, but I've never used it.