# Trash extremely slow ubuntu 16.04 when used for big files

Tags: ram, swap, delete, trash

I am re writing the question to avoid confusion...
On Ubuntu 16.04 I had to delete about 6500 files. 50% were RAW images and 50% were associated .XML files. Totalling 72GB. I am using Samsung Evo SSD 500GB. 
I actually moved the files to rash first and then deleted them.
I noticed that just moving the files to the trash consumed all my RAM (8GB) and all my SWAP (8GB). 
Is there a setting that can make the Trash in Ubuntu behave more efficiently? I know I can force delete the files and bypass trash altogether but that defeats the purpose of the trash completely. Or is this behaviour expected?

Comment: Might be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1571540 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1133477

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This behavior is expected, because when you delete something using nautilus, it just moves it to the trash, as you know.</strike>

Correction: This is *not* the expected behavior. As BB1 points out, 'moving' a file to the trash doesn't actually move it anywhere, it just updates it's inode to reflect the location.

I would guess that your ram is being eaten because it takes much more system resources to delete (or do anything with) a bunch of small files than it does to delete one bigger file.

The [behavior of Trash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-delete.html) doesn't appear to be very customizable. There's not much that be done about that, unfortunately. You could look into [`trash-cli`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74269/intercepting-calls-to-rm-and-directing-deleted-files-to-trash-instead?rq=1), but I don't know if it would be more efficient or not.

When I have to delete a bunch of small files, I always do it from the shell, because it's faster. Even then, I have encountered an error while trying to delete nearly a 100k files, something along the lines of "rm: argument list too long". To get around that, I ran rm in a for loop and iterated through the files like:

```
for letter in {a..z};do rm -f $letter*;done
```

If you wanted to emulate the trash functionality in the shell, you could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
## pseudotrash
elsewhere=/media/$USER/some-external-drive/pseudo-trash
for file in "$@";do
  cp $file $elsewhere
  if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] ; then
    rm -f $file && echo "Backed up and deleted $file"||\
    (echo "Could not delete $file , aborting";exit 1)
  else
    echo "Could not copy $file,aborting" ;exit 1
  fi
done
```

And than run it like:

```
pseudotrash `ls`
```

or

```
pseudotrash 'file1 file2 file3'
```

I hope that answers your question and offers some insight to help solve your problem.

Comment: Why is the behaviour expected? The file when moved to trash is with the same inode. So the file didn't "move" physically.  The added info is under "~/.local/share/Trash/info" and contains the original location and time stamp. Is this that can consume 8GB Ram and 8GB Swap?

Comment: I cannot utilize the script. I use darktable and in the case I have moved specific files (3000 out of 4000) in the trash - not the complete content of the folder. Currently the only way in this case is to disable trash. I have very serious doubts if trash is intended to consume so much RAM, SWAP and CPU. My expectation is that this is a bug.

Comment: You're right, that's not the typical expected behavior.  I will correct the answer. My bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is (was) a very annoying bug in Nautilus (package gvfs):

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1571540
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1133477

But just 3 days ago this bug was fixed and the fix version added to repositories.

> [2017-08-28](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1133477/comments/74): 
>   This bug was fixed in the package gvfs - 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2

Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to update to the new version.