# copying/deleting files never ends in ubuntu

Tags: delete, trash, copy

I just deleted some files from directory but deleting progress never ends, it happens often, once I didn't turn off pc 3 days and progress was still not finished.. what might be the problem?

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Maybe the problem is `71.835 files` .. browsing through that number of files can be a problem.

Comment: I guess that is a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848400/trash-extremely-slow-ubuntu-16-04-when-used-for-big-files) but cannot mark as duplicate, because of no upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is (was) a very annoying bug in Nautilus (package gvfs):

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1571540
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1133477

But just 3 days ago this bug was fixed and the fix version added to repositories.

> [2017-08-28](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1133477/comments/74): 
>   This bug was fixed in the package gvfs - 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2

Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to update to the new version.